# Почему setInterval быстрее?

Tags: javascript, функции, setinterval, settimeout

> Есть два бегуна:
>
> ```
> var runner1 = new Runner();
> var runner2 = new Runner();
> ```
>
> У каждого есть метод step(), который делает шаг, увеличивая свойство steps.
>
> Конкретный код метода step() не имеет значения, важно лишь что шаг делается не мгновенно, он требует небольшого времени.
>
> Если запустить первого бегуна через setInterval, а второго – через вложенный setTimeout – какой сделает больше шагов за 5 секунд?

```
function Runner() {
  this.steps = 0;

  this.step = function() {
    this.doSomethingHeavy();
    this.steps++;
  };

  function fib(n) {
    return n <= 1 ? n : fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
  }

  this.doSomethingHeavy = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      this[i] = fib(i);
    }
  };

}

var runner1 = new Runner();
var runner2 = new Runner();

// запускаем бегунов
var t1 = setInterval(function() {
  runner1.step();
}, 15);

var t2 = setTimeout(function go() {
  runner2.step();
  t2 = setTimeout(go, 15);
}, 15);

// кто сделает больше шагов?
setTimeout(function() {
  clearInterval(t1);
  clearTimeout(t2);
  alert( runner1.steps );
  alert( runner2.steps );
}, 5000);
```

Про работу методов setTimeout() рекурсивного и setInterval() в разных браузерах мне  всё понятно. Не понятно одно:в данном коде при вызове  рекурсивного setTimeout(в силу его специфики: фиксированной паузы между вызовами) срабатывает функция doSomethingHeavy(), а при вызове метода setInterval, эта функция не срабатывает  сразу идёт подсчёт шагов,вызовы идут  равномерно один за другим. Именно поэтому setInterval быстрее?

Comment: Если в doSomethingHeavy вы добавите какой-нибудь console.log, то увидите, что она работает в обоих случаях (почему ей не работать-то)

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval  Немного вниз прокрутите, там есть картинки

Comment: при `setInterval` - время выполнения функции не учитывается, при `setTimeout` - каждый новый запуск планируется только после окончания текущего

Comment: Хорошо,тогда объясните мне, зачем в функцйии  doSomethingHeavy цикл for?  И откуда это число 25 там?Почему 25?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl согласно названии функции, она делает *тяжелую* работу. Число 25 взято просто так, как оптимальный вариант для *тяжелой* работы.